# Differences in Sklearn and Elasticsearch results for TFIDF

Tags: python, elasticsearch, scikit-learn

I am working on document similarity. My first approach was to use Sklearn's implementation of the TFIDF algorithm. The results are fine, but for many documents search was slow.

Then I set up Elasticsearch, using `elasticsearch_dsl` in Python. I understand my query is using also TFIDF:

```
s = s.query(MoreLikeThis(like=string,
                         fields=fields,
                         min_doc_freq=100,
                         max_doc_freq=175000))
```

However, the results are *very* different! I have just implemented [vector-based search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#script-score-query-ex-request), as allowed in Elasticsearch 7.3. This allows me to take Sklearn vectors and use them in Elasticsearch. My results are not identical, but very close (as expected, similar to what I hoped to see with the Elasticsearch `MoreLikeThis` query!). So it seems clear that TFIDF in Elasticsearch is not working as in Sklearn.

[image]
This image shows scores for a query. At left, scores for Sklearn vs Sklearn vectors in Elasticsearch. At right, Sklearn vs Elasticsearch using my query above (of course, I have used the same parameters, as well as a thorough exploration of different ones trying for a better match).

Is this to be expected? Or should I assume this is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, latest elasticsearch uses as default slightly different algorithm than TF/IDF, namely BM25. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/similarity.html

Comment: I see in that link that BM25 is the default, but that I can switch to TFIDF... that is interesting. If this is the case, I should be able to get more similar results. I will check.

Comment: Apparently that part of the documentation is outdated and the TFIDF option is no longer available, so I can't have the definitive proof I was looking for, but it seems like you are correct indeed.